# Is a pattern matching switch statement guaranteed to happen in order?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

In the following code, is `result` guaranteed to be `1`, or are there no ordering guarantees and could it also return `2`?

```cs
record Foo
{
    bool X { get; init; }
    bool Y { get; init; }
    bool Z { get; init; }
}

var foo = new Foo { X = true, Y = true };
var result = foo switch
{
    { X: true } => 1,
    { Y: true } => 2,
    { Z: true } => 3,
    _ => 0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a *switch expression*, not a switch statement.

Yes.

> The result of a `switch` expression is the value of the expression of
> the first `switch` expression arm whose pattern matches the input
> expression and whose case guard, if present, evaluates to `true`. The
> `switch` expression arms are evaluated in text order.

From *[switch expression - pattern matching expressions using the switch keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression)* (Microsoft Learn)

Comment: Could also be worth taking a look at what actually gets compiled after lowering using a decompiler like [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABM3AYVwG9NcL88EAWXAWQAoBKU8yjgNwgCdcAzAPaDcAXlwwApgHdcAMWGlcADTG4ALjwCukgDS4Amms07cAXwDc7DhW58ekgM5aANurVCRj6VHUBjAAtrGzIMG3ClZRANbUlzMQA+XBRdYIilA2iTOLNE3CRUsPTKElwALSzY+NEk7ELiygB9PIAGNMpLdoou/BQATkYHZzdmKyKKM0xJjEwHP0EeABN5YUxQjhxcYGEXFSUAc0l1C1xYXxPpjbxtwV2jUsPj05hz82DNm92yg6OTs6fpmYgA==)

Comment: @MindSwipe Just looking at the behavior of the implementation does not give any long term guarantees. I wouldn't want to update to the new .NET version and suddenly have my code break.